# Сделать обрабочик кнопки для вызова функции. Т.е. при нажатии на кнопку должна запускаться функция. telebot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Возникла проблема, сам увы не могу справиться с ней. У меня есть 2 файла, main где находить основной код бота и кнопки и registration где происходит проверка и регистрация пользователя. Как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку "Работодатель"(128 строка) в файле main, запускалась функция с названием send_welcome_employer (47 строка) в файле registration.
main

```
from telegram import Update, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler
import mysql.connector
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from config import TOKEN
import requests, telebot, logging, sys
from telebot import types, apihelper
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import mysql.connector




try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="host",
        user="user",
        passwd="passwd",
        port="port",
        database="database"
    )
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Что-то не так с вашим именем пользователя или паролем")
        sys.exit()
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("База данных не существует")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print(err)
        sys.exit()

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_employer"
mycursor.execute(sql)
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
number_registered_employers = rows[0][0]  # сколько человек зарегистрировано(Работодатели)
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_workers"
mycursor.execute(sql)
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
number_registered_workers = rows[0][0]  # сколько человек зарегистрировано(Работодатели)
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applications"
mycursor.execute(sql)
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
number_applications = rows[0][0]  # сколько человек зарегистрировано(Работодатели)

logging.basicConfig(format='[LINE:%(lineno)d]# - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
id_group = -1001159001919  # 756515243#
user_data = {}


class User:
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city

        keys = ['phone', 'date_work_start',
                'date_work_finish', 'time_work', 'place_work',
                'quantity_people', 'type_payment', "much_pay"]

        for key in keys:
            self.key = None


FIRST, registration_button, setting_button, main_menu_button, \
post_requests_button, feedback_button= range(6)

def start(update, context):

    user = update.message.from_user
    logger.info("Пользователь %s запустил команду start.", user.last_name + user.first_name)
    img = open('D:\Photo\wallapper\\17706.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(update.message.chat.id, img)
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton('Зарегистрироваться', callback_data=str(registration_button)),
         InlineKeyboardButton('Настройка', callback_data=str(setting_button))],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('Заявка', callback_data=str(post_requests_button))],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('Обратная связь', callback_data=str(feedback_button))]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text("Ура! Вы - в главном меню!\n Добро пожаловать в бота для поиска работы, "
                           "для работодателей представляеться прекрасная возможность в короткий срок "
                           "найти ответсвенных работников для проведения скорых работ. В свою очередь для "
                           "работников представляеться возможность в короткий срок заработать\n---\nРаботодателей: "
                           + str(number_registered_employers) + "\nРаботников: " + str(number_registered_workers) +
                           "\nКоличество размещенных заказов: " + str(number_applications) +
                           "\n---\nДля начала работы нажмите одну из кнопок ниже:", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return FIRST


def start_over(update, context):  # Запрашивать тот же текст и клавиатуру, что и` start`, но не как новое сообщение
    bot = context.bot
    img = open('D:\\Photo\\wallapper\\17706.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(update.message.chat.id, img)
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton('Зарегистрироваться', callback_data=str(registration_button)),
         InlineKeyboardButton('Настройка', callback_data=str(setting_button))],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('Заявка', callback_data=str(post_requests_button))],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('Обратная связь', callback_data=str(feedback_button))]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text("Ура! Вы - в главном меню!\n Добро пожаловать в бота для поиска работы, "
                              "для работодателей представляеться прекрасная возможность в короткий срок "
                              "найти ответсвенных работников для проведения скорых работ. В свою очередь для "
                              "работников представляеться возможность в короткий срок заработать\n---\nРаботодателей: "
                              + str(number_registered_employers) + "\nРаботников: " + str(number_registered_workers) +
                              "\nКоличество размещенных заказов: " + str(number_applications) +
                              "\n---\nДля начала работы нажмите одну из кнопок ниже:", reply_markup=reply_markup)
    return FIRST



def registration_menu(update, context):  # при нажатии на первую кнопку (Зарегистрироваться)
    query = update.callback_query
    bot = context.bot
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Работодатель", callback_data=str(" ")), # СТРОКА 128
         InlineKeyboardButton("Работник", callback_data=str(" "))],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню", callback_data=str(main_menu_button))]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=query.message.message_id,
        text="Выбирете кто вы, для регистрации в бд ",
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )
    return FIRST


def setting_menu(update, context):  # при нажатии на вторую кнопку (Настройка)
    query = update.callback_query
    bot = context.bot
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Данные о себе", callback_data=str(" ")),
         InlineKeyboardButton("Данные вашей заявки", callback_data=str(" "))],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню", callback_data=str(main_menu_button))]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=query.message.message_id,
        text="Что вы хотите изменить??",
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )
    return FIRST


def post_requests_menu(update, context):  # при нажатии на третью кнопку (Разместить объявление)
    query = update.callback_query
    bot = context.bot
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню", callback_data=str(main_menu_button))]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=query.message.message_id,
        text="ТУТ ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ ФОРМА ДЛЯ РАЗМЕЩЕНИЯ ОБЪЯВЛЕНИЯ",
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )
    return FIRST


def feedback_menu(update, context):  # при нажатии на третью кнопку (Разместить объявление)
    query = update.callback_query
    bot = context.bot
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню", callback_data=str(main_menu_button))]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    bot.edit_message_text(
        chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
        message_id=query.message.message_id,
        text="Напишите нам, чего не хватает в боте  \
                Мы всегда рады обратной связи от неравнодушных пользователей!\
                Здесь вы можете поделиться позитивным, негативным опытом, предложить сферы деятельности, категории, параметры фильтрации и т.д.",
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )
    return FIRST


def error(update, context):
    logger.warning('Обновление "%s" вызвало ошибку "%s"', update, context.error)



def main():
    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    # ^ означает "начало строки"
    # $ означает "конец строки"
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            FIRST: [CallbackQueryHandler(registration_menu, pattern='^' + str(registration_button) + '$'),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(setting_menu, pattern='^' + str(setting_button) + '$'),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(post_requests_menu, pattern='^' + str(post_requests_button) + '$'),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(feedback_menu, pattern='^' + str(feedback_button) + '$'),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(start_over, pattern='^' + str(main_menu_button) + '$')]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('start', start)]
    )

    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)
    dp.add_error_handler(error)
    updater.start_polling()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

registration

```
import requests, telebot, logging, sys
from telebot import types, apihelper
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import mysql.connector

try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(  # даныне бд
        host="host",
        user="user",
        passwd="passwd",
        port="port",
        database="database"
    )
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Что-то не так с вашим именем пользователя или паролем")
        sys.exit()
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("База данных не существует")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print(err)
        sys.exit()

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')
user_data = {}

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help_list(message):
    a = ['/help ' + 'Информация\n', '/reg_employer ' + 'Регистрация работодателя\n', '/reg_workers '+'Регистрация работника']
    for i in a:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, i)

class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = ''
        self.middle_name = ''
        self.phone_number = ''
        self.subjects_civil_law = ''
        self.region = ''
        self.services_provided = ''
        self.age = ''

@bot.message_handler(commands=['reg_employer'])  # Работодатель 

def send_welcome_employer(message):# СТРОКА 47
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    list = []
    sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users_employer "
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    rows = mycursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        list.append(row[0])
    if user_id not in list:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите Ваше имя: ", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_lastname_step_employer)
    else:
        sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users_employer WHERE user_id LIKE %s"
        val = (user_id,)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        rows = mycursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            first_name = row[0]
            last_name = row[1]
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы уже зарегистрированы, " + first_name + " " + last_name)


def process_lastname_step_employer(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user_data[user_id] = User(message.text)
        user = user_data[user_id]

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите Вашу фамилию: ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_middlename_step_employer)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, "ooooooooooooops ")


def process_middlename_step_employer(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.last_name = message.text

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите Ваше отчество: ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_phonenumber_step_employer)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'ooooooooooooops')


def process_phonenumber_step_employer(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.middle_name = message.text

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите Ваш номер телефона: ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_subjects_civil_law_step_employer)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'ooooooooooooops:')


def process_subjects_civil_law_step_employer(message):
    try:
        a = int(message.text)
        if len(str(a)) == 11:
            user_id = message.from_user.id
            user = user_data[user_id]
            user.phone_number = message.text

            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
            itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Физическое лицо')
            itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Юридическое лицо')
            markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2)

            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Укажите вы являетесь юридическим или физическим лицом: ",
                                   reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_region_step_employer)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(process_subjects_civil_law_step_employer)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Не являеться номером телефона. Пожалуйста введите номер телефона.')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_subjects_civil_law_step_employer)


def process_region_step_employer(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.subjects_civil_law = message.text
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Укажите Ваш город: ", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_services_provided_step_employer)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Вы ввели что-то не верное')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_region_step)


def process_services_provided_step_employer(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.region = message.text

        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
        itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Строительство')
        itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Проектирование')
        itembtn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Программирование')
        itembtn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Оказание услуг в сфере обслуживания')
        itembtn5 = types.KeyboardButton('Грузовые перевозки')

        markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2, itembtn3, itembtn4, itembtn5)

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Каким видом деятельности вы занимаетесь: ", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_last_step_employer)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')


def process_last_step_employer(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.services_provided = message.text
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
        sql = "INSERT INTO users_employer (first_name, last_name, middle_name, phone_number, subjects_civil_law, region, services_provided, user_id) \
               VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (
            user.first_name, user.last_name, user.middle_name, user.phone_number, user.subjects_civil_law, user.region,
            user.services_provided, user_id)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        mydb.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Вы успешно зарегестрированны," + " " + user.first_name + " " + user.middle_name,
                         reply_markup=markup)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message, "ooooooooooooops")






@bot.message_handler(commands=['reg_workers'])
def send_welcome(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    list = []
    sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users_workers "
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    rows = mycursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        list.append(row[0])
    if user_id not in list:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите Ваше имя: ", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_lastname_step)
    else:
        sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users_workers WHERE user_id LIKE %s"
        val = (user_id,)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        rows = mycursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            first_name = row[0]
            last_name = row[1]
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы уже зарегистрированы, " + first_name + " " + last_name)


def process_lastname_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user_data[user_id] = User(message.text)
        user = user_data[user_id]

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите Вашу фамилию: ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_middlename_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, "ooooooooooooops ")


def process_middlename_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.last_name = message.text

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите Ваше отчество: ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_phonenumber_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'ooooooooooooops')


def process_phonenumber_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.middle_name = message.text

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите Ваш номер телефона: ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'ooooooooooooops:')


def process_age_step(message):
    try:
        a = int(message.text)
        if len(str(a)) == 11:
            user_id = message.from_user.id
            user = user_data[user_id]
            user.phone_number = message.text

            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Укажите Ваш возраст: ")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_region_step)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(process_age_step)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Не являеться номером телефона. Пожалуйста введите номер телефона.')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step)


def process_region_step(message):
    try:
        int(message.text)
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.age = message.text
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Укажите Ваш город: ", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_services_provided_step)
    except Exception as e:
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Не являеться номером возрастом. Укажите Ваш возраст:')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_region_step)


def process_services_provided_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.region = message.text

        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
        itembtn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Строительство')
        itembtn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Проектирование')
        itembtn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Программирование')
        itembtn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Оказание услуг в сфере обслуживания')
        itembtn5 = types.KeyboardButton('Грузовые перевозки')

        markup.add(itembtn1, itembtn2, itembtn3, itembtn4, itembtn5)

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Каким видом деятельности вы занимаетесь: ", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_last_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')


def process_last_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user.services_provided = message.text
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)
        sql = "INSERT INTO users_workers (first_name, last_name, middle_name, phone_number, age, region, services_provided, user_id) \
               VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (
            user.first_name, user.last_name, user.middle_name, user.phone_number, user.age, user.region,
            user.services_provided, user_id)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        mydb.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         "Вы успешно зарегестрированны," + " " + user.first_name + " " + user.middle_name,
                         reply_markup=markup)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message, "Вы уже зарегестрированны," + " " + user.first_name + " " + user.middle_name)
```

Если напрямую в callback_data передаю функцию send_welcome_employer, он выдает ошибку:
"send_welcome_employer() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
не смог понять понять какие аргументы передает, поэтому добавил просто *args

А если в send_welcome_employer передать *args, то будет такая ошибка:
'Update' object has no attribute 'from_user'
И как тут исправить я не знаю.

Строго не судите, пока только учусь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если я всё правильно понял из Вашего вопроса, то вот пример:

файл А:

```
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper
from telebot import types
from file_b import test_func

bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot)
apihelper.proxy = proxy

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def some(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    test_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Тест', callback_data='test_button')
    keyboard.add(test_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нажми на кнопку', reply_markup=keyboard)

# Inline keyboard
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'test_button':
       test_func()  # если нужно передать message используйте test_func(call.message)
```

файл Б:

```
def test_func():
    a = 1 + 1
    return a
```

Comment: Правильно, НО в файле Б как аргумент функции надо передать message. Но тогда я не понимаю что надо передавать как аргумент для функции в файле А

Comment: эм, я вроде указал, разве не то?
test_func()  # если нужно передать message используйте test_func(call.message)

и в файле Б будет например def test_func(message): print(message.text)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я сделал это благодаря вам. Я просто не так давно в программировании и не понимал как я могу передать аргумент функции правильно. Но с call.message все сработало, правда не понимаю как но работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Что именно непонятно как работает?

Comment: Как работает аргументы функций, ну типа почему если я передам не call.message а просто message он не будет работать. А именно с call.message работает

Comment: И еще вопрос есть, а если в файле Б написано bot.register_next_step_handler(тут имя следующей функции в файле Б) т.е. бот ссылается на следующею функцию, как тогда? Например так, https://pastebin.com/jMuMXaeh. Т.е. функция которую вы вызываемым ссылаться на следующею, но если это как то не обозначить в файле А, то будет работать только та которую мы вызываем

Comment: > если я передам не call.message а просто message он не будет работать:
потому что при callback message содержится в call.message.

> bot.register_next_step_handler:
нет смысла вызывать это в файле Б, ведь объект bot у вас в файле А.

если требуется через bot.register_next_step_handler вызвать новую\другую функцию из файла Б, то импортируйте ее в файле а (from file_b import new_func), а после используйте bot.register_next_step_handler(send, new_func).

send в этом случае будет, например, bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите что-нибудь')

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснение, учиться мне еще и учиться )