# Как на Python для телеграмм-бота привязать готовую функцию к кнопке?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram, openweathermap

Уже готова функция - определение погоды в любом городе. Но мне надо привязать функцию к кнопке. Т.е. кнопка при запуске бота появляется под сообщением, нажимаешь, и бот предлагает узнать погоду.

```
button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(...?)
markup.row(button1)
```

Таким образом можно сделать? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```py
button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Текст кнопки", callback_data="weather_button") # замените Текст кнопки на свой
markup.row(button1) # в этой строке ничего не изменилось
```

Потом, ниже в коде, написать обработчик:

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'weather_button':
       # тут вызываете всё что нужно, например, если функция называется
       # weather, то вызываете weather(), а если нужно передать message, используйте weather(call.message)
       # или если просто нужно использовать message, то используйте call.message
```

*<sup><sub>Частично взято из ответа [@Violet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/234134/violet) [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1100017/548252).</sub></sup>*

Comment: Так вот именно, что мне нужно без обработчика как-нибудь. Я могу прислать вам функцию для данной команды, так, как она у меня написана.

Comment: @User В смысле "без обработчика"?